# Using gksu with command-line parameters

Tags: command-line, ibus, gksu

How do I use a program command-line parameters with gksu?

I have a program that takes parameters.

```
gksu myprog --dataload --maximize
```

But then I get an error **IBus error Folder .... owner is not root**

Searching tells me I should be using `gksu` but then it takes the parameters for `myprog` as parameters for itself and says `--dataload` is not a command and then shows the help page.

Kinda in a loop here. So, how to use gksu and myprog or should I...

1. Continue to use gksu and ignore the IBus error?
2. Change ownership of the Folder to root?

Answer (score 1):

Just quote your command:

```
gksu "myprog --dataload --maximize"
```

Alternatively, use `--` which signifies the end of options. Anything after that, even if it begins with a `-`, will not be taken as an option to `gksu`:

```
gksu -- myprog --dataload --maximize
```

Comment: Thanks, but neither options  seem to work. It goes off somewhere for about 5 seconds then returns to the Terminal-prompt. I moved the "--" to after "myprog" and it ran the program without the error, but then myprog didn't understand the "--" before it's parameters.

Comment: No, the `--` can't be after `myprog`, it needs to be after `gksu` to tell gksu not to process any other options. If you add it later, it tells `myprog` to ignore the options. I've tested both of these approaches and they do work. If they don't in your case, I would guess the problem is with `myprog` and not `gksu`.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help and sorry for the confusion it was my assumption and omission. I should have mentioned that was on the second try after the placement right after gksu as you showed, did the same thing.  Quotes didn't work, nor did **gksu --** or **gksu myprog --** I even tried quotes **gksu -- myprog "--data..."** - all wandered off for five seconds and did nothing.

Comment: @X10WannaBe then it's an issue with `myprog`. As I said, I tried `gksu firefox --new-tab "http://example.com"` and it failed as you describe but both `gksu 'firefox --new-tab "http://example.com"'` and `gksu -- firefox --new-tab "http://example.com"` worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears to be an issue with Ubuntu 14.4. **gksu -- veracrypt --auto-mount favorites** goes off for  few seconds and does not launch veracrypt. And, the same when using quoted options **plus** your two Firefox examples, all fail. I'll just assign root as the owner of the Folder in question that seems to get around the error.